# Page with same name as subfolder not resolving after removing .php extension using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

so I have a relatively simple site where all the pages have a .php extension, i.e about.php, gallery.php etc. I also have a services.php file and also a subfolder in the directory named **services**. For greater clarity my structure is below:

```
root
|
|-index.php
|-about.php
|-gallery.php
|-services.php
|-contact.php
|-services/
  |-service-one.php
  |-service-two.php
  |-service-three.php
  |-service-four.php
```

As you'll see I have a services.php and services folder. In the root I have the following htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This allows about.php, for example, to be accessed without the .php extension so http://www.domain.com/about works as about.php would. However when I try http://www.domain.com/services, I get neither the directory listing or the services.php page. I get the following message which gives a couple of clues.

```
The requested URL /services/.php was not found on this server.
```

I've been unable to find a way to resolve this, I'm wondering if I need an htaccess in the /services folder?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tweak your regex to match everything before last `/`:

```
DirectorySlash Off
Options -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]
```

Also note modification in `RewriteCond` to check for existence of `.php` file.

Comment: Yes agreed. However, the problem in OP's rule is not just the same file/directory name. If the request comes with a trailing slash e.g. `/about/` then also it will fail. Another problem is `RewriteCond`

Comment: This has got me somewhere, thankyou but still not quite at the point I want to be. I now get the directory listing / the index when going to http://www.domain.com/services . I've tried a few other things to no avail, one thing that would get round the issue is to include and index.php file within the /services folder. Then I can just put the services.php content within this index.php file. Sound a bit messy / risky though having two index.php files within the project though.

Comment: If URL is `http://www.domain.com/services` then do you want to show content of `http://www.domain.com/services.php` or want to show content from `http://www.domain.com/services/index.php`?

Comment: Scrap the index.php idea. I want to show http://www.domain.com/services.php if the URL is http://www.domain.com/services

Comment: Yes, pretty much spot on that is! Thank you very much. Only issue is the homepage on the localserver (http://localhost/domain) throws an Access forbidden! error unless I make it http://localhost/domain/ . However on the live server (http://www.domain.co.uk) it is fine.

Comment: Thanks, still getting Access forbidden! Without the trailing slash (localhost/domain)

Comment: ok comment out `Options -MultiViews -Indexes` line and retest.